# FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry how do i insert sslmode='require' into my Python code

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I can't log into my SQL.  Heroku  says insert `sslmode='require'` into my Python code but they show a different example:

```
import psycopg2
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```

but i don't use that is use this:

```
engine = create_engine("postgres://iykazvclamrzem:140bdec1e446a9119d4fb1c9e20d89fb17716e702de72b7be09f2b2e53b86d36@ec2-50-19-127-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d134n6bd1767sd")
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

Where do I put the `sslmode='require'`   ?

Comment: You read the docs [SQLALCHEMY](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2)SSL Connections

Answer (score 0):

In [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) you will find:

> The general form for a connection URI is:
>
> `postgresql://[userspec@][hostspec][/dbname][?paramspec]`
>
> where `userspec` is:
>
> `user[:password]`
>
> and `hostspec` is:
>
> `[host][:port][,...]`
>
> and `paramspec` is:
>
> `name=value[&...]`

So you should use an URI like this:

```
postgres://username:password@hostname:5432/dbname?sslmode=require
```